# How to create an image in Java SWT without display

Tags: java, swt

I am learning SWT with the goal to create a wizard. I am modifying an existing tutorial. At this point, I am trying to display an image in one page of the wizard:

```
class FrontPage extends WizardPage {

  FrontPage() {
    super("FrontPage");
    setTitle("Listes des joueurs");
    setDescription("Veuillez déplacer toutes les listes dans le même fichier (ex: C:\\Badminton\\)");
  }

  public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    composite.setLayout(gridLayout);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(composite, SWT.NONE);
    canvas.setBounds(10, 10, 693, 253);

    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
      public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        Image image = new Image(null, "C:\\Benoit\\Work\\Java\\Badminton\\Folder_List_Players.png");

        e.gc.drawImage(image, 10, 10);

        image.dispose();
      }
    });

    setControl(composite);

  }
```

}

When running this code, my image, which is roughly 600 by 200, is displayed as a thumbnail (10x10). I would like to display it full size.

1. I understand that I might have a Display object in the Image constructor, but I am unsure how to make it work with the Composite parent object. It is interesting however that I am still able to display the image with a null Display object.
2. The canvas.setBounds(10, 10, 693, 253); does not seem to have any impact.

Thanks in advance for any hints or help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an Image is created with a null Display, the current Display is used. For clarity, you should always provide a Display when creating images.

And there is no shortage of references to the current display either, for example:

```
Display display = event.display;
```

or

```
Display display = parent.getDisplay();
```

In order to display an image, prefer using a `Label` like this:

```
Label imageLabel = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
imageLabel.setImage( ... );
```

To layout controls, stay away from using setBounds() and absolute coordinates. Use layout managers instead: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much, my image now displays properly!

Comment: @BenoitGoderre `Display.getCurrent()` or `Display.getDefault()` are other ways to get the display.